# SQL Server Pivot Assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

SQL Server. It may be solved by using Pivot.

I have data (all are in string):

```
    X     Y     Z     ---Heading

    A     a     p
    A     b     q
    A     c     r
    B     a     s
    B     b     t
    B     c     u
```

I want output:

```
     a    b    c     ---Heading

A    p    q    r
B    s    t    u
```

Comment: Please provide more information and code that you had already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `case` expression. here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=211c18b988d3a51e222adeed5494af0f).

```
select
  X,
  max(case when Y = 'a' then Z end) as a,
  max(case when Y = 'b' then Z end) as b,
  max(case when Y = 'c' then Z end) as c
from myTable
group by
  X
order by
  X;
```

output:

```
| x   | a   | b   | c   |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A   | p   | q   | r   |
| B   | s   | t   | u   |
```